# Having trouble finding an old PCB -- R.L. Drake, 1992, P/N 3100678/8825

Tags: pcb

I have a circuit board from an R. L. Drake product, but I'm having trouble finding the product. The board has been turned into a clipboard, with all the components removed. I looked around on the Internet, and the closest I could find is the Drake R8 Communications Receiver, but the circuit board didn't look similar in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXJE1NP5S6Q). Below is an image of the information part of the board.

[image: imformation block on board]

Comment: Have you asked R. L. Drake?

Comment: There's a CD-ROM with many, many R.L. Drake equipment manuals available (not for free) at this website: http://www.hamanuals.com/Series1.html .  If you're planning to assemble that PCB you're going to need a detailed schematic! Man, I loved my Drake 2B 60 years ago...

Comment: It's actually been cut into a clipboard shape and size, so I can't assemble it, unfortunately. I just want to know which of their products it's from.

Comment: How about a picture of the other side? Are there component designators? Might be able to get more clues.